# codeigniter mysql session cookie issue

Tags: database, session, cookies, codeigniter-3, config

I am upgrading ci 2 to ci 3.11
I have done all the changes in upgrading,
Still i get this error

Error Number: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `id` = 'gr6rnf66t7d20oqlkocr5ate3nlg3equ'' at line 2

SELECT 1 WHERE `id` = 'gr6rnf66t7d20oqlkocr5ate3nlg3equ'

Filename: D:/xampp/htdocs/XXXX/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691

I want to know from while file this database querying.
Just now i found that if i change
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
this value id in the query is changing

For now i changed to sess_driver to files in config to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't give $config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions'; (Its the table name of session)